# Apple Contacts LDAP Schema

Tags: mac-osx, ldap

I am trying to create an LDAP directory that will contain all of my contacts and sync between my devices. Of course, I want all of the contact information I supply to match up with Apple Contacts' fields. I have searched all over the Internet for some matching between LDAP fields and Apple Contacts' fields. What is the mapping of LDAP fields to Apple Contacts fields, or where can I find such a mapping?